Why is the story of Dhul Qarnayn so similar to Syriac Alexandar legend?
The story of Dhul Qarnayn in Sura Kahf is very similar to the Syriac Alexandar legend, including key narratives like travelling to the setting and rising places of sun and sealing of the Gog and Magog using a barrier which is prophesized to break in the future.
Muslim scholars mostly seem to agree that Alexandar couldn't be Dhul Qarnayn since historically Alexandar was a polytheist while Dhul Qarnayn is a firm believer. The bigger problem is historians unanimously agree that this legend is just that, a legend, and doesn't have any historical basis. Moreover, the prominent hypothesis is that this story was created as propaganda and the prophecies are ex-eventu.
Why would Quran's narration shares so much similarity with a legend that has very questionable origins? And does the Quran's narration meant to be taken as literal history or is it possible to interpret it as an allegorical story?
References
There has been many papers written by secular academics on this topic. Some notable ones -

Kevin van Bladel, “The Alexander Legend in the Qur’an 18:83-102,” in The Qur'an in Its Historical Context (2008), edited by Gabriel Said Reynolds
Tommaso Tesei, The Syriac Legend of Alexander's Gate: Apocalypticism at the Crossroads of Byzantium and Iran (2023)
Stephen Shoemaker, The Apocalypse of Empire, University of Pennsylvania Press 2018, pp. 79-86.
Marianna Klar, "Qur'anic Exempla and Late Antique Narratives," in Oxford Handbook of Quranic Studies, Oxford University Press, 2020.


Sami Amri wrote about this in his book Shubuhaat Tarikhiyyah.

@TheZ could you summarize what he wrote? I can't read Arabic.

I will do that perhaps in a week.

It is agreed upon that surat al-Kahf was revealed in the Meccan period and the date of revelation was between 615-620 BCE which predates the Legend by 10 years.

@Medi1Saif Components of the legend existed from 1st century in the writings of Josephus. The Syriac version is argued to have existed in a different form already in 6th century according to other researchers (Shoemaker and Tesei). https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syriac_Alexander_Legend#Dating
Note that Quran acknowledges the existence of Dhul Qarnyn's legend in 18:83 "And they ask you about Dhul-Qarnayn".

In the name of Allah
The Alexander Syriac story was written after the quran was witnessed and heard.
More for info and evidence check out
https://hejaziphilosophorian.home.blog/2019/12/11/was-the-quranic-dhul-qarnayn-a-plagiarism-of-the-alexander-romances/

This only addresses Van Bladel's thesis. Other researchers like Shoemaker and Tesei have argued that the legend already existed in some form as early as 6th Century https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syriac_Alexander_Legend#Dating
And components of this story already existend in 1st century writings of Josephus. The Quran itself acknowledges people's knowledge of the story in 18:83 "And they ask you about Dhul-Qarnayn".

If you read the site you would know it address Josephus and the other things you said

In the name of Allah
First the Quran addressed the Jews who knew about dhul qarnayan and some scholars view him as Cyrus. Alexander story is not a historical accounts and could be false attributions of a true historical event in Dhul qarnayan altered to fit in Alexander
